# How to pass by Retrofit Header and Field Maps with Paging Library

Tags: android, paging, android-architecture-components, androidx

So, I was looking into the new [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) by android. It has different components that you need to implement to have it work. Let's say I want to hit an API with retrofit and endlessly scroll with pagination updates. What is the best way to pass by the Header or Field maps to Retrofit considering all the stuff that you need to implement( ViewModel, repository, data source etc)? 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit is nothing to do with PagingLibrary, you will handling the retrofit you handled before.
If you want to send a BasicAuth header with retrofit, then here is a code.

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.retrofitandroidtutorial.api;

import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

    private static final String AUTH = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("belalkhan:123456").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://simplifiedlabs.xyz/MyApi/public/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;


    private RetrofitClient() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(
                        new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                Request original = chain.request();

                                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                        .addHeader("Authorization", AUTH)
                                        .method(original.method(), original.body());

                                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                                return chain.proceed(request);
                            }
                        }
                ).build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public Api getApi() {
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

The above code will put the same header to every retrofit call that you will made.

The same thing you will use in the methods like loadInitials(), loadBefore() and loadAfter() to get your required pages.

For example below is my Retrofit API interface.

```
public interface Api {

    @GET("answers")
    Call<StackApiResponse> getAnswers(@Query("page") int page, @Query("pagesize") int pagesize, @Query("site") String site);
}
```

Here I have the call metod that is taking the parameters like page number, page size to fetch the data.

The same way you will call it in the paging methods. An example is below:

```
  //this will be called once to load the initial data
    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<Integer, Item> callback) {
        RetrofitClient.getInstance()
                .getApi().getAnswers(FIRST_PAGE, PAGE_SIZE, SITE_NAME)
                .enqueue(new Callback<StackApiResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<StackApiResponse> call, Response<StackApiResponse> response) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            callback.onResult(response.body().items, null, FIRST_PAGE + 1);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<StackApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

I hope this helps. If you want a step by step explanation of using Android Paging Library with PageKeyedDataSource then follow this **[Android Paging Library Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paging-library-tutorial/)**.

And for learning about Retrofit and Building APIs I have published a complete series on youtube. You can check [Retrofit Android Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxKwuUOLGEc&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hhGfJw-IQCm6kjywmuJX4Rh).

Answer (score 0):

Being as you posted the PagingWithNetworkSample which uses the Reddit API, in that sample, your Retrofit Field annotations would probably be in the equivalent of this file:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/api/RedditApi.kt

Your Retrofit Header would probably go in that file as well.

In the RedditApi class, functions such as getTop and getTopAfter are being called from other parts of the app.  For example from here -

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/d81da2cb1e3d61e40f052e631bb15883d0f9f637/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/repository/inDb/SubredditBoundaryCallback.kt#L54

So if by "the best way to pass by the Header or Field maps to Retrofit" you mean which way do you pass Header and Field values to Retrofit, in this example it would be from the functions in SubredditBoundaryCallback calling getTop and getTopAfter (with those values perhaps being passed into SubredditBoundaryCallback from somewhere else).